# changing /var/www to /srv gets 403

Tags: linux, apache, web, permissions

I'm used to working with `/srv` as the webroot for apache. After creating a new CentOS machine, the default DocumentRoot is set to `/var/www/html`. I've changed this `/srv`, but I'm getting a 403 when I visit my domain.

From the default httpd.conf file that was created, I changed the following:

```
DocumentRoot "/srv/www/html"

<Directory "/srv/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "/srv/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This is a `ls -lhA` in `/srv`:

```
rwxrwxrwx. 3 root root 34 Jan 29 06:51 www
```

I `777`d the directory just to get it to work. I'll be changing this after I figure out what's wrong. `chmod -R a=rwx /srv` is what I did.

Comment: Is your CentOS server running SELinux? If so, you would need to change the context of `/srv` to match that of `/var/www/html`.  A default CentOS install would be running it. Check with `getenforce`. If `Enforcing`, SELinux is enabled.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski It does indeed say `Enforcing`... I'll look into what switching context is, and see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, CentOS runs SELinux in `Enforcing` mode, which enforces additional security limits on the filesystem. In order for SELinux to permit Apache to read filesystem locations, they must have the correct SELinux context.

The typical context for `/var/www/html` is `httpd_sys_content_t`. You'll need to set that context on `/srv/www` using `/usr/bin/chcon`.

```
# Set the correct context for readable web server documents
$ chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t /srv/www
```

To do so recursively, use `chcon -R`.  I would not expect that you need to set that context on the parent `/srv`, but target `/srv/www` specifically.  Afterward, be sure to limit the normal `chmod` filesystem permissions from the the `777` you currently have.

If you have paths which must be writable by the Apache web server, in addition to making those writable with `chmod` ,you'll need to set a read/write context: `httpd_sys_rw_content_t`.

To list contexts used by Apache and known to SELinux, and the paths they belong on, run:

```
$ semanage fcontext -l | grep httpd
```

To check the context on an existing file, use the `-Z` flag to `ls`. This can help you match the right context for your new directory.

```
$ ls -lZ /var/www

drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_script_exec_t:s0 4096 Jan  4 02:25 cgi-bin
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0     4096 Jan  4 02:25 html
```